# Listener events not being triggered

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

I have been playing around with the documentation whilst learning ExtJS. But when testing listener events nothing will happen.

I have generated a modern app using sencha CMD. I deleted all the code that wasn't needed and then added my own based on the documentation. However the listener events just don't seem to work at all. I have tried with several examples and no luck.

What could be the problem?

One example is -

**Main**

```
Ext.define('ListenerTesting.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.layout.Fit'
    ],

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',


    tabBarPosition: 'left',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'click me',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Success", "Message");
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: For modern [button](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.Button.html#events) there is no `afterrender` event in docs. Can you explain exactly what you want ?

Comment: For any modern component, not just button.

Comment: I just noticed this too. Also was trying to use "click" and discovered its now "tap".

I am just trying to display a message via alert once a panel has been loaded.

Comment: Have you tried the "painted" event? painted: function() { Ext.Msg.alert("Success", "Message");  }